# Space between controls in SAPUI5

Tags: html, sapui5

I tried to insert space between two controls inside MatrixLayoutCell in sapui5. However, it is giving and error. My code is :

```
var control = new sap.m.Input("id_mtr_kra_rating_val", {
        value : "Something",
        width:"70px"
        });

var control3= new sap.ui.core.HTML("htmlspace",{
        content:"&nbsp;"
        });

var control2 = new sap.m.Label("percentlabel",{
    text:"labelText"
    });

var cell= new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayoutCell("idcellmtr",{
           content:[control1,control2,control3]
            });
matrixLayout.createRow(null,cell,null );
```

It is giving an error : Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:   
Is this the right way to do this? If not, please help me with the solution.
Thanks.

Comment: The error is in this line: `matrixLayout.createRow(createRow(null,cell,null );` where you have an unrecognized expression `createRow`, probably a copy-paste error

Comment: @Qualiture It is not a copy paste error as it is working when I dont give the html space i.e control2.

Comment: I just simply could not work... have a closer look at this line: `matrixLayout.createRow(createRow(null,cell,null );` where it has a secondary function `createRow` and you are missing a closing `)` in the end

Comment: @Qualiture sorry for the typing mistake here. I edited the post and It is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at it, you are only placing a simple nonbreaking space to the DOM, whereas I think it would expect something that can be added to the DOM.

You can try using `<span>&nbsp;</span>` instead and see if that works.

But a better approach would be to use an empty spacer cell -- if you want padding between the matrixlayout columns -- or add some extra padding using the `attachStyleClass` method -- if you want spacing between controls inside a column